# jQuery animation code doesn't work on Google Chrome, works on Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, google-chrome

Ok, so I have this code, which animates the background of a table element.

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mRm/2/)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="foo2">Some Random Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function doItOn(el) {    
    var backgroundColor = el.css("backgroundColor");
    el.css("backgroundColor", "yellow");
    el.animate({backgroundColor: backgroundColor}, 2000);
}

var table = $("<table><tr><td>Dynamic td</td></tr></table>");

doItOn($("#foo2"));
doItOn(table.find("tr"));

$("body").append(table);
```

This works on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

However, if I move `doItOn(table.find("tr"));` below `$("body").append(table);`, it works in both. ([JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/n6mRm/3/))

Why does this happen?

Edit: I'm using jQueryUI too, as jQuery doesn't support backgroundColor animations.

Comment: On Safari (Mac), both Fiddles work correctly, even though Safari and Chrome share the same lay-out engine. What OS and browser version are you using?

Comment: Your first Fiddle throws an error in Chrome, but the seconds one doesn't. Kinda makes sense since you are trying to animate the background color of an element that hasn't been added to the DOM yet.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Chrome 21, Firefox 15 on Mac 10.7.2. Did you try it on Chrome?

Comment: I just tried it again, and it doesn't work in Safari anymore. I think I messed up the order previously. I never got it working in Chrome. If is dissect your JS, you try to fetch all table rows when you perform `doItOn(table.find("tr"))`, but then you add another row with `$("body").append(table)`, which isn't passed to the animate function because you created it afterwards. This is expected behaviour under WebKit: JS statements are executed in order. However, if Firefox is trying some optimisation tricks, this might explain the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably unpredictable behaviour. The jQuery docs say for the `.animate()` function this:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but **`background-color` cannot be**, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

**Edit:** This doesn't apply when using jQuery UI.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I _am_ using jQuery UI too.

Comment: @user1527166 Ah. Then you lost me — I'm not a regular jQUI user… :-p